# Is the supremum of a right continuous process right continuous? Defining a stopping time as the first hitting time of a supremum process

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

This is a question that came to my mind while reading Lemma 13 of the notes here : https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/23/localization/

In this lemma, the writer assumes $X$ is a right-continuous adapted process such that $X_t^*$ is almost surely finite for all $t$ and the filtration is only a completed filtered space with no assumptions on right-continuity. $X_t^*$ is defined as $\sup_{s\in [0,t]} |X_s|$. The proof itself is simple but states without justification that $$\tau_n = \inf \{t\ge 0: X_t^* \ge n\}$$ is a sequence of stopping times.

I believe this follows from the Debut theorem given here in Theorem 2 :https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/

But then we would need that $X_t^*$ is a right continuous adapted process. However, I cannot prove this fact.  Is this true or is there another justification for this being a stopping time here? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X_t^*$ is nondecreasing, $\{\tau_n\le t\}=\{X_t^*\ge n\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$ because $\{X_t^*\}$ is [adapted](https://almostsuremath.com/2016/11/08/measurable-projection-and-the-debut-theorem/#scn_mp_lem5).

Comment: Thank you so just to be clear this doesn’t have to do with Debut theorem and $X^*$ may not be right continuous when $X$ is?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician The running maximum of a cadlag process is increasing and right-continuous.

Comment: Could you help me see how it is right continuous?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician $X_t^*(\omega)$ jumps at $t$ only if $X_t(\omega)$ has a positive jump at $t$ such that $X_{t-}^{*}(\omega)<X_t(\omega)$. In this case, $\lim_{s\downarrow t}X_s^*(\omega)=\lim_{s\downarrow t}(X_s(\omega)\vee X_t(\omega))$.